# PySpark: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am trying to execute some simple `pyspark` scripts to test our installation of Apache Spark within our Kubernetes cluster.

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("spark://<host>:<port>")
    .appName("SparkSession")
    .getOrCreate()
)

print(f"PySpark Version : {spark.version}")
print(f"PySpark Version : {spark.sparkContext.version}")
```

However, when running the script I get this error:

```
22/05/04 13:07:48 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
```

I have been able to reach the cluster using `telnet <host> <port>`, the Spark WebUI is available on the local network and the workers are listed as available.
[image: screenshot_webui]

The `spark-shell` also works fine from the master pod. I've checked the version number on my machine and the remote, and they are the same `3.2.1`.

Has anyone encountered the something similar? What causes the error?